# Prove this point is on the circumcircle

Tags: geometry

[image]

I have a triangle $DCE$ with $DC>DE$. The exterior angle bisector of $\angle CDE$ meets the perpendicular bisector of $CE$ at $H$. How do I prove that $H$ always lies on the circumcircle of $CDE$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of circumcircle ($O$) is on perpendicular bisector of $CE$. It's sufficient to prove that $OD = OH$. Let $G$ the point on $CE$ such that $DG$ is perpendicular to $CE$. Let $K$ the point on CE such that $HK$ is perpendicular to $CE$. It's clear that $DG$ is parallel to $HK$. We note that $\angle{CDO} = \angle{EDG}$ because $\angle{EDG} = \frac{\pi}{2}-\angle{DEC} = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\angle{COD}}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(\pi-\angle{COD}) = \angle{CDO}$, the last equality is due $\triangle{CDO}$ is isosceles. Let $x = \angle{EDG}$, we see that $\angle{OHD} = x + \angle{EDG}$ (because $DG$ is parallel to $HK$) and $\angle{HDO} = x+\angle{CDO} = x+\angle{EDG} = \angle{OHD}$ and this equality implies that $OD = OH$ and we conclude.